# checking for duplicate values before attempting insert (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, select, duplicates

I have a form where two fields on the first page of the form make up the primary key. I want to check for duplicate values before attempting to insert the record, since I don't want the user to go all the way through the form only to find out they can't submit it. So I'm trying to check for duplicate values when the user tries to go to the next page of the form. I wasn't quite sure how to do it, and sure enough I'm getting an error. ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") The problem is apparently in my if statement, "If myValue.Length > 0 Then", but I'm not sure what needs to be in place of that.

```
Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate

    'get values
    Dim checkPrefix = txtCoursePrefix.Text
    Dim checkNum = txtCourseNum.Text

    'db connectivity
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = AccessDataSource1.ConnectionString
    myConn.Open()

    'select records
    Dim mySelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT prefix, course_number FROM tableCourse WHERE prefix='checkPrefix' AND course_number='checkNum'", myConn)

    'execute(Command)
    Dim myValue As String = mySelect.ExecuteScalar()
    'check if record exists
    If myValue.Length > 0 Then
        CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "some exp text"
        CustomValidator1.SetFocusOnError = "true"
        CustomValidator1.IsValid = "false"
    End If

End Sub
```

Thought I'd post the final solution:

```
'select records
    Dim mySelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT 1 FROM tableCourse WHERE prefix=? AND course_number=?", myConn)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkPrefix", checkPrefix)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkNum", checkNum) 

    'execute(Command)
    Dim myValue = mySelect.ExecuteScalar()

    'check if record exists
    If myValue IsNot Nothing Then
        CustomValidator1.SetFocusOnError = True
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that the content of myValue variable is null. If it's null you can't use Length property (or any other property for that matter) on it. You have to check for null explicitly:

```
If myValue IsNot Nothing Then
```

**EDIT 1**
Your sql query is wrong. I don't know what would be the right query, as I don't know your database, but I think you intender to write this:

```
Dim mySelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT prefix, course_number FROM tableCourse WHERE prefix=" + checfkPreix + " AND course_number=" + checkNum, myConn)
```

or something to that effect. You might want to consider using [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) function for forming the string. And you also need to make sure that there is some kind of protection against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), since you form your query from user input. In your case using of [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) might be appropriate.

**Edit 2**

You also right to mention that there might be a problem with ExecuteScalar. ExecuteScalar is supposed to return a single value and your select query are returning two (prefix and course_number). Change it so that it returns a single parameter `SELECT prefix FROM` or simply `SELECT 1 FROM` and then the rest of the query:

```
Dim mySelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT 1 FROM tableCourse WHERE prefix=? AND course_number=?", myConn)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkPrefix", checkPrefix)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkNum", checkNum)
```

**Edit 3** 
You are not setting failed validation properly in your validator.
Add

```
 args.IsValid = False
```

inside your if statement.

Comment: Tried that and same thing happened as with the one above, there's no error anymore but it doesn't stop me when I enter a duplicate value.

Comment: This means that the query you are using for checking the duplicate value is wrong. It returns null, where as you expect it to return something else. Resolve this and it will solve your issue

Comment: Oh of course it's wrong! Look at how you pass parameters! You are not actually passing them, they way you wrote it, they are just literals, part of your string!

Comment: Okay thanks, I edited it in the original post, but I don't think I did it right. What I have now still isn't working. Do I need to use ? in place of @checkPrefix and @checkNum?

Comment: What you put in the last end *looks correct* but you saying that it's still not working. What is your database and can you a) try and run this query directly against the database and b) see what query actually come through from you application to the database?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access. I can try running it against the database I think although I have never really worked directly with Access surprisingly (besides building simple tables), and don't know how to use queries directly in Access. But I can try.

Comment: Sorry, your last-last edit is wrong what you used to have before was right. If you use the OleDbParamerer, as you shown before, you don't need these values in the sql query string. I advise to revert back to previous incarnation and investigating that database data and what's coming through to the database.

Comment: Alright. Well I'm thinking the query is right, but the mySelect.ExecuteScalar() is wrong... I'm thinking it can't be a string.

Comment: Oh, you are quite right. Execute Scalar returns just one value. And You are returning two in your query. Change "SELECT prefix, course_number FROM tableCourse" to "SELECT prefix FROM tableCourse" or simply to "SELECT 1 FROM tableCourse"

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. But the problem is, I need to check both prefix and course_number together. Should I use ExecuteNonQuery? -EDIT- Or no, ExecuteReader?

Comment: You don't need to *retrun* them both together. You check them both, but then you return a single value, and it does not matter what value this is, you even can return constant 1, just to indicate that there was a match. You should be able to do this with ExecuteScalar and it's the simplest.

Comment: Tried that, it is still saying there's a data type mismatch and highlighting "Dim myValue = mySelect.ExecuteScalar()"

Comment: Did you revert back to the option that did not get the error before?

Comment: Ok, I updates the query in my EDIT 2, could you please try that?

Comment: Okay tried that, and nothing happens. No error, but the validator doesn't catch that I entered a duplicate value. I think the other query was right.

Comment: This is correct. We are almost there. Now change your if statement to this "If myValue IsNot Nothing Then" and then I think we are home.

Comment: Did that. The validator isn't doing anything though.

Comment: Can you step through and make sure that code inside your if where you set your validator properties is executed?

Comment: -EDIT- Actually it is getting executed. But the validator just isn't responding. Going to look at it and see if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: See my Edit 3 - you are not letting the system know that validation has failed.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you SO much! I can't believe you gave this much time to help me. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Oh unfortunately I have to have 15 reps to upvote, sorry. But I accepted it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`myValue` is null if there is no duplicate, so you have to apply `.Length` only if `myValue` is not null (which means checking for `null` only is enough; without `.Length`)

```
If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue) Then
```

Comment: Isn't there an implied Length > 0 in Not String.IsNullOrEmpty?

Comment: Thanks, tried it, I'm not getting the error anymore but it's not stopping me when I enter a duplicate value...

Answer (score 0):

First `ExecuteScalar` will only return a single value, so in this case you are only going to get the column `prefix` from the result. Second if there is no match with your query it will return `null`, so your next length check should account for that scenario:

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue) Then
...
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try something like this instead (you will have to adapt it to VB.Net) DBNull is different from Null or Nothing so you have to compare it to both

```
If myValue <> DBNull and not myvalue is nothing Then
```